# Multiple file removal in PHP

Tags: php

Hello everyone and thanks in advance!
The thing is that I have 2 files named *'test3.txt'* and *'text2.txt'* in my folder. The thing I want to do is to remove both of them storing them in an array. Firstly I check if files exist with *'file_exists'* method and then when I try to remove them it fails. I know I am doing something wrong but I did little research and couldn't find my answer to this problem. What am I trying to do is to remove these both files at once if it's possible somehow.

```
1  <?php
2 
3  $files = array('test3.txt', 'text2.txt');
4  $exists = false;
5  
6  foreach ($files as $file) {
7      if (file_exists($file)) {
8      $exists = true;
9      }
10 }
11 
12 if ($exists == true) {
13     unlink($files);
14     echo "Files were successfully deleted";
15 }
16     else {
17         echo "Couldn't delete files";
18     }
```

Browser returns True though files are still aren't removed from the directory.
Here's the browser output:

```
 Warning: unlink() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /var/www/html/web/copy.php on line 13
Files were successfully deleted
```

Comment: The documentation of the `unlink()` functions clearly says that it expects a string as first argument, a filename. Not an array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the `unlink()` functions clearly says that it expects a string as first argument, a filename. Not an array.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

You could try something like that instead of manually iterating over the files:

```
<?php
$files = ['test3.txt', 'text2.txt'];
array_map('unlink', $files);
```

(Just tried myself... works!)

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify it a bit...

```
<?php

$files = array('test3.txt', 'text2.txt');

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
        echo $file . " was successfully deleted";
    } 
    else {
        echo $file . " does not exist.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You check each file but try to delete all of them together. You should unlink each file one by one.

```
  $files = array('test3.txt', 'text2.txt');
  $exists = false;

  foreach ($files as $file) {
      if (file_exists($file)) {
      $exists = true;
      }
 }

 if ($exists == true) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
       unlink($file);
    }
     echo "Files were successfully deleted";
 }
 else {
    echo "Couldn't delete files";
 }
```

Would be better write like this:

```
 foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`unlink($files);` -- you send array, but not filename.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

And you have one proplem more here:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $exists = true;
  }
}
```

if one of files is exists -- you take $exists is true. Try some like this:

```
<?php
$files = array('test3.txt', 'text2.txt');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
  }
}
echo "Files were successfully deleted";
```